# How to make an autocomplete input field dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, autocomplete

I have an input field which when a user clicks into it and begins typing, i need a dropdown to show up which displays all the dropdown options that begin with what is being typed. I have most of the functionality already I just cant figure out how to get it to filter through the array and display only the relevant options.

[image]

```js
    const ampInput = document.querySelector('.amp-input');
    
    const ampDropdown = document.querySelector('.amp-dropdown-container');
    const ampOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.amp-options');

    ampInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
      ampDropdown.classList.add('amp-dropdown-container--active')
    })

    ampInput.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
      ampDropdown.classList.remove('amp-dropdown-container--active')
    });

    ampInput.addEventListener('input', onInputChange)

    function onInputChange() {
      const value = ampInput.value.toLowerCase();

      const filteredOptions = [];

      ampOptions.forEach((option) => {
        if (option.innerHTML.substr(0, value.length) === value)
          filteredOptions.push(option);
      });
      // console.log(filteredNames)
    }
```

```html
<form action="{{ routes.search_url }}" method="get" role="search" autocomplete="off">
          <ul>
            <li id="autocomplete-wrapper">
              <input 
                id="autocomplete-input"
                type="search" 
                placeholder="Amp Hours (aH)" 
                class="amp-input">
                <ul class="amp-dropdown-container">
                  <h5 class="volt-options-title">Top Searches</h5>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">1.3</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">2.2</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">3.4</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">4.5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">7</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">8</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">8.5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">9</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">10</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">12</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">14</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">18</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">20</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">22</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">26</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">32</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">33</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">35</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">50</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">55</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">70</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">75</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">100</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">110</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">120</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">155</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">170</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">200</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">220</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">250</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">270</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">300</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">325</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">330</div></li>
                  <li><div class="last-link">400</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul> 
        </form>
```

Comment: what's `voltInput`?

Comment: thats for a different input field sorry (not needing to do any work for this one)

Comment: the focus in on the amp input stuff

Comment: instead of this `filteredOptions.push(option);` try pushing only the html value: `filteredOptions.push(option.innerHTML);` You can see it working in console.

Comment: Just made the changes and that does return the value within the console when console logged, however now I somehow need to get the dropdown that pops up to only show the values that begin with what is typed into the input field. If that makes sense

Comment: so these values that are returned need to now create a new dropdown, each time something else is typed narrowing down again etc

Comment: I posted an answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can associate an empty `datalist` element to to the search input (I added it on bottom of your html code). Note the attribute `list="suggestions"` added to the search input, which instructs it to populate a suggestion box picking elements from the datalist.

Then, on search input change, you can store your filtered results dynamically as `option` elements of the datalist, making the search input show a suggestion box.

```js
//const voltInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
const ampInput = document.querySelector('.amp-input');
const ampDropdown = document.querySelector('.amp-dropdown-container');
const ampOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.amp-options');
const suggestions = document.getElementById('suggestions');

ampInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ampDropdown.classList.add('amp-dropdown-container--active')
})

ampInput.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
  ampDropdown.classList.remove('amp-dropdown-container--active')
});

ampInput.addEventListener('input', onInputChange)

function onInputChange() {
  const value = ampInput.value.toLowerCase();
  const filteredOptions = [];
  suggestions.innerHTML = ''

  ampOptions.forEach((option) => {
    if (option.innerHTML.substr(0, value.length) === value) {
      suggestions.innerHTML += '<option value="' + option.innerHTML + '">'
      filteredOptions.push(option.innerHTML);
    }
  })

  console.log(filteredOptions)
}
```

```html
<form action="{{ routes.search_url }}" method="get" role="search" autocomplete="off">
          <ul>
            <li id="autocomplete-wrapper">
              <input 
                id="autocomplete-input"
                type="search" 
                list="suggestions"
                placeholder="Amp Hours (aH)" 
                class="amp-input">
                <ul class="amp-dropdown-container">
                  <h5 class="volt-options-title">Top Searches</h5>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">1.3</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">2.2</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">3.4</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">4.5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">7</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">8</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">8.5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">9</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">10</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">12</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">14</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">18</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">20</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">22</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">26</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">32</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">33</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">35</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">50</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">55</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">70</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">75</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">100</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">110</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">120</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">155</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">170</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">200</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">220</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">250</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">270</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">300</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">325</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">330</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options last-link">400</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul> 
        </form>
        
        
        <datalist id="suggestions"></datalist>
```

- EDIT

This update (per OP's comment) handles the filtering directly on the `<ul>` element:

```js
//const voltInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
const ampInput = document.querySelector('.amp-input');
const ampDropdown = document.querySelector('.amp-dropdown-container');
const ampOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.amp-options');
const suggestions = document.getElementById('suggestions');

ampInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ampDropdown.classList.add('amp-dropdown-container--active')
})

ampInput.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
  ampDropdown.classList.remove('amp-dropdown-container--active')
});

ampInput.addEventListener('input', onInputChange)

function onInputChange() {
  const value = ampInput.value.toLowerCase();
  const filteredOptions = [];

  ampOptions.forEach((option) => {
    if (option.innerHTML.substr(0, value.length) === value) {
      option.parentElement.classList.remove('hidden')
    } else {
      option.parentElement.classList.add('hidden')
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="{{ routes.search_url }}" method="get" role="search" autocomplete="off">
          <ul>
            <li id="autocomplete-wrapper">
              <input 
                id="autocomplete-input"
                type="search" 
                placeholder="Amp Hours (aH)" 
                class="amp-input">
                <ul class="amp-dropdown-container">
                  <h5 class="volt-options-title">Top Searches</h5>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">1.3</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">2.2</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">3.4</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">4.5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">7</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">8</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">8.5</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">9</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">10</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">12</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">14</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">18</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">20</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">22</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">26</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">32</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">33</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">35</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">50</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">55</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">70</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">75</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">100</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">110</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">120</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">155</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">170</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">200</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">220</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">250</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">270</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">300</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">325</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options">330</div></li>
                  <li><div class="amp-options last-link">400</div></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul> 
        </form>
```

Comment: ahh its so close! ive added a pic of what happens after adding your changes. the larger dropdown is the original one i have made while the smaller one is the one added with your code. Is there any way to get that small list to be displayed within my dropdown container? the functionality seems to work correctly with the list

Comment: Ok, added an update to my answer according to your request.

Comment: wow cant thank you enough been pulling my hair out for days trying to figure this out. Thanks a lot :)